# Using the java checker framework, why is a NonNull value not accepted into a Nullable value location?

Tags: java, null, typechecking, checker-framework

Using the java checker framework, why is a Map NonNull value not accepted into a Map Nullable value location?

With this code invocation:

```
        schema.validate(
            MapMaker.makeMap(
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                    "foo",
                    "baz"
                ),
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                    "bar",
                    2
                )
            ),
            configuration
        );
```

I get this error:

```
java: [argument] incompatible argument for parameter arg of validate.
  found   : @Initialized @NonNull Map<@Initialized @NonNull String, @Initialized @NonNull Object>
  required: @Initialized @NonNull Map<@Initialized @NonNull String, @Initialized @Nullable Object>
```

And the validate method is defined as:
`public FrozenMap<@Nullable Object> validate(Map<String, @Nullable Object> arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException, InvalidTypeException {`

Any non null Object is a subset of the set of nullable Objects, so why does this not work?
How do I get this to work for non-nullable key input also?
Do I need to have a different input method signature for the nullable and the non-nullable input arg?

My arguments passed in to the validate method will be used for reading only. Per the checker framework javadocs, @Covariant may be a solution here:
`For example, consider Iterator. A client can read elements but not write them, so Iterator<@Nullable String> can be a subtype of Iterator<String> without introducing a hole in the type system. Therefore, its type parameter is annotated with @Covariant. The first type parameter of Map.Entry is also covariant. Another example would be the type parameter of a hypothetical class ImmutableList.`

But that only applies to interfaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) Generics are invariant. This also applies to checkerframework. A `Map<String,@NonNull Object>` is not a `Map<String,@Nullable Object>` since the latter allows -inserting_ a `null` value while the former must not have any `null` values.

Comment: You could try using a `Map<String,?>` in the signature of `validate`.

Comment: Why are you referencing the Dog/Animal example? Both of these types are String, either un-annotated or annotated. Are you referencing it because the type checker treats @Nullable String as a different type than String which is synonymous with Dog/Animal?

Comment: Because the same reasoning applies. Checkerframework treats `@NonNull T` as a subtype of `@Nullable T`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is happening because the checker framework sees

- String
- @Nullable String
  as two different classes, where String (@NonNull String) [inherits from @Nullable string](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#fig-nullness-hierarchy)
  Like in normal Java, covariance does not apply.

So the solutions here are to:

1. use extends to allow covariance like `public FrozenMap<@Nullable Object> validate(Map<String, ? extends @Nullable Object> arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException, InvalidTypeException {`
2. update the validate method to accept `Map<String, ?>` This is not great because type checking info is lost from the signature
3. or write many methods that accept all combinations with/without @Nullable like `Map<String, @Nullable Object> arg` `Map<String, Object> arg`
4. or write an interface that makes a generic parameter for each nullable parameter, and implement it.

Number 4 example code would look like

```
@Covariant(0)
public interface MapValidator <InType extends @Nullable Object, OutType> {
    OutType validate(Map<String, InType> arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException, InvalidTypeException;
}

public class SomeSchema implements MapValidator<@Nullable Object, FrozenMap<@Nullable Object>> {
    OutType validate(Map<String, @Nullable Object> arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException, InvalidTypeException {
        ...
    }

}
```